# MSE or MO? Ambiguity in the quality of the questions, and boundary of eligible questions, which are eligible to be asked on MO.

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow

Since the beginning of my membership, it happened for me too many times, that I had a question, which I thought that I will not receive a good answer on MSE. Also, I didn't have enough courage and self-confidence to ask it in MO, so I didn't ask it there. Also, I've seen too many questions which "are not in the research level" in MO, and there were just graduate questions. Anyway, because of the lack of bravery and self-confidence, and also the ambiguity in the "boundary of eligible questions" to be asked on MO, almost I prefer not to ask my questions. Even I didn't have enough courage to ask this question here, also I don't what are the suitable tags for this question.

Comment: What's your question here?  I don't think there is anything like a set of hard and fast rules that will tell you where a math question belongs.  MSE is, by and large, for questions which admit short, definitive answers.  That includes some quite difficult questions, of course!   MO is for open ended research questions where one hopes to gain some insight (and maybe some information regarding partial results) from the community.  As you remark, the borderline is not sharp.

Comment: @lulu I don't think that MO is for open-ended questions.

Comment: @quid  In that case,  what distinction would you draw?  Just the difficulty of the underlying material?

Comment: @lulu it's complex. There are various posts on the subject written. Over time things also evolved. I'd say mostly it is a question of level. MO gives more  leeway regarding the form of questions, and sometimes the scope. But overall it is also for clear cut questions that admit a definite answer.

Comment: @quid  Ok.  My experience with that site is rather dated at this point so I'd have missed any "evolution".

Comment: @lulu Usually, I'm used to asking my questions in great detail, and that makes me think about the chance to get an answer before asking. And if I feel like I probably won't get an answer, I won't spend my time writing questions. I was looking for two of my deleted questions so I could cite them, but I could not find them. The title of one of them is exactly "A question on adelic functions",and the other is almost "Clifford algebra of a non-diagonal quadratic form over rings"[I ask it later again]. Another reason I do not ask my questions is that I am afraid that my questions will be ridiculous

Comment: I looked over some of your non-deleted questions on MSE and so no obvious problems.  Users there object to homework questions or, more generally, to anything mechanical where the impression is that the OP isn't interested in making the slightest effort...but those objections don't apply to your posts.  All of which is to say that I think you can have some confidence in your ability to post solid questions.